Can I force a Kubernetes pod to only connect to the Aurora instance residing in the same AZ?
Basically looking for ways to reduce latency between an app in EKS and RDS/Aurora as much as possible, and want to try a test where I only allow pods in say us-east-1a to talk to the DB in that same AZ.
So far, I'm thinking I could introduce some environment variable foolery to the container init script where I either set the DB endpoint/reference a secret containing that endpoint, but then I am creating a single point of failure where there is no failover, which defeats the point of having it multi-AZ.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
